# Crossfade two images with CSS and stop at the end

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to crossfade from one image to another and stop at the end.

Currently my code looks like below.
Unfortunately the target image f2 doesn't stay and reverts to a white background.

```css
.fadein {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
.fadein img {
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

#f2 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadein">
    <img id="f1" src="https://dummyimage.com/320x180/fff/aaa">
    <img id="f2" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/180">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it's starting at `opacity: 0` and ending at `opacity: 0`. You need to change so that when the animation ends the `opacity:1` is set to one.

```css
.fadein {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.fadein img {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#f1 {
  animation-name: fadeout;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#f2 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadein">
  <img id="f1" src="https://dummyimage.com/320x180/fff/aaa">
  <img id="f2" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/180">
</div>
```

Comment: That's almost perfect, but I forgot to mention that they shouldn't fade out and in after another, instead they should simultaneaously fade from one to another. Is that possible  as well?

Comment: @lmoly just updated. You can adjust the keyframe stages as you need.